# PyGTK + threading; windows unexpectedly freezes

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk, freeze

I'm trying to manage files containing "other files" (lots of small files stored in a few large files). The "engine" works quite good, but I have some problems with GUI. Some functions are threaded because of processing time, for example deleting or adding files. Here's part of the code:

```
import gtk, os, data, time, threading, subprocess
import Image, re
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

#some unimportant code - creating window with some buttons and IconView item (to show elements in currently opened directory)
    def _del_thread(self): #deletes items selected in gtk.IconView
        dl, fl = self.items #self.items stores selected dirs and files
        for d in dl:
            self.changestatus('Deleting: '+data.dirs[d][0]+'...') #prints the text at StatusBar (data.dirs[d][0] is a filename)
            data.RemoveDir(d) #recursively removes all content in directory d
        for f in fl:
            self.changestatus('Usuwanie pliku: '+data.files[f][0]+'...')
            data.PopFile(f) #removes single file
        self.changestatus('') #clears the StatusBar
        self.refresh() #some elements are deleted - refresh IconView

    def _add_thread(self, fl): #adds files listed in fl
        for f in fl:
            self.changestatus('Adding: '+f[-50:]+'...')
            #some unimportant code (recognizing file's extension and generating a thumbnail
            data.PutFile(f, thumb, self.dir) #adds the file with generated thumbnail to currently opened directory (self.dir)
        self.changestatus('') #clears the StatusBar
        self.refresh() #some elements are added - refresh IconView

    def Delete(self, widget): #triggered by clicking a context-menu item
        md = gtk.MessageDialog(None, gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, \
                               gtk.MESSAGE_QUESTION, gtk.BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL, \
                               "Do you want to remove selected items?")
        res = md.run()
        md.destroy()
        if res == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self._del_thread) #start new thread
            t.start()

    def Add(self, widget): #triggered by clicking a context-menu item
        chooser = gtk.FileChooserDialog(title='Select files to add...',action=gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                                        buttons=(gtk.STOCK_CANCEL,gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,gtk.STOCK_OPEN,gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        chooser.set_select_multiple(True)
        response = chooser.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            #star new thread with selected files' list as an argument
            t = threading.Thread(target=self._add_thread, args=(chooser.get_filenames(),))
            t.start()
        chooser.destroy()
```

There's also third function run in a thread, but it's unimportant. It is fast (~1 sec), always executes fine and never freezes the window. The other two ones (shown above) sometimes executes well, sometimes not. For example, I select some files in FileChooserDialog, the adding thread starts, StatusBar showing consecutively the files are being added now, and at the end the window freezes. After that the window looks like that (sorry for the polish description):
[image: pygtk window + threading, window freezes]
Why does thread sometimes process without problems, and sometimes doesn't?

Best regards,
mopsiok

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the problem. According to http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show , I had to add gtk.threads_enter() before every gtk function in thread, and gtk.threads_close() after it. Now it seems to work fine.